# php adding 1 hour to the timestamp

Tags: php, datetime, time, timestamp, datediff

I am trying to add 1 hour to a `timestamp` field fetched from database using the following code.

```
date($ls['created_at'], strtotime('+1 hour'));
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. It returns the same time as in database. Am I missing something? Or, is the code deprecated? What is the proper solution?

Comment: @the_previ Yes, of course mate! You didn't read my question properly I guess. I mentioned it returns the same date as in database. That means the timestamp is correct and works well. It's just not adding up the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give it the correct syntax to use this,
You need to send the time to change with the change itself in the function - for example (using date for wanted format):

```
$date = "22-02-2021 14:22:22";
echo date("d-m-Y H:i:s", strtotime($date.' +1 hour'));
```

This will return:

```
22-02-2021 15:22:22
```

Same as this:

```
echo date("d-m-Y H:i:s", strtotime("22-02-2021 14:22:22 + 1 hour"));
```

The idea is that you strtotime receives the date and data to change in one string like this :

```
echo strtotime("22-02-2021 14:22:22 + 2 hour");
```

Will return:

```
1614010942
```

Here I removed the Date Format so I received a unix timestamp format

Comment: I used format - meant to say syntax, of strtotime. The date function is only there to set the output format.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Don't worry. I used the variable here. Also, I totally understood what he is trying to explain in his answer.

Comment: @RelaxingMusic - That's good, but it's not just for your benefit. Answers are here to help future visitors with similar issues as well so they should be as correct as possible :-)